# Вывод float без экспоненты

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Код:**

```
declare
    @DealID bigint=31129,
    @Formula nvarchar(50) 
BEGIN
    declare @premium float,
        @date_end date,
        @date_begin date

        select @date_end=d.DateEnd
              ,@date_begin = d.DateBegin
              ,@premium=p.InsPremia 
        from   Deals d (nolock)
        inner join Products p on p.DealID = d.ID
        where d.ID=@DealID
begin
set @Formula = 
           cast(@premium as nvarchar) +'/'+cast((Datediff(d,@date_begin, @date_end)+1) as nvarchar)                 
end
    select @premium premium,@Formula formula
END
```

Результат запроса:

```
premium     formula
63571070    6.35711e+007/359
```

Ожидаемый результат:  `63571070/359`
Попробовал поменять тип `@Formula nvarchar(50)  на float`
Но ошибка:
`Error converting data type nvarchar to float`
Как преобразовать?

Comment: Преобразуйте float к decimal а потом к varchar.

Comment: вместо cast(@premium as nvarchar) используйте STR(@premium)

Comment: В SqlServer 2012 и далее доступна функция [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh213505.aspx): `declare @premium float = 63571070; select format(@premium, 'F0');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас возможна проблема потери информации либо её искажение:

```
DECLARE @premium FLOAT = 63571070.543453 
SELECT @premium, CAST(@premium as nvarchar) + N'/395'
    , CAST(CAST(@premium as DECIMAL(32,16)) as VARCHAR) + N'/395'
    , CAST(CAST(@premium as DECIMAL) as VARCHAR) + N'/395'
```

В этом примере вы можете получить искажённые данные как: `63571070.5434530004858971/395` либо потерять десятичную часть: `63571071/395`
Чтоб избежать таких проблем либо сразу не используйте `FLOAT` либо задавайте необходимую максимальную точность как: `DECIMAL(10,5)`